# Pick random item from array and populate - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Id like to have an array containing 10 different recipes, on each page load i want to populate a div with one of these recipes, Im new to arrays but im not sure why nothing is alerting here?

```
var recipes = [{
    "image": "image1.jpg",
    "ingredients": {
        "a": "eggs",
        "b": "chips"
    },
    "link" : "google.com"
}, {
    "image": "image2.jpg",
     "ingredients": {
        "a": "chocolate",
        "b": "cheese"
    },
    "link" : "msn.com"
}];

var recipe = recipes[0];

alert(recipe);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6otvzr1p/1/

Comment: I get `[object Object]` which is the normal output of `alert` when asked to show a JS object.

Comment: `recipes[0].image` is what u want in your href of a?

Comment: To get a random array object use `var randomRecipe = recipes[Math.floor(Math.random() * recipes.length)];`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting the correct value only . Parse the recipes object and put the required value .
You can use this code to get the random number between 0 and 9 which can be passed as index to array

**`Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))`**